# Changing user settings in the registry for other than current user

Tags: windows, registry, autoit

How would I go about changing the HKCU registry for a user other than the current user?  I don't have any other information but the user name.  I will be using AutoIT for the actual execution, but if it's AutoIT's RegWrite or if I have AutoIT run a command or execute a .reg file is not important.  The core problem is accessing the HKCU registry for a different user based on the user name.

Comment: [HKCU is just a pointer to `HKEY_USERS\SID of current user`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976337.aspx), so all you need to do is look up the other user's security ID. (I got that link from [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532874/1454048)).

Comment: You can't do this without the password, or at least not in a way that works in all scenarios.  Consider, for example, that the user's registry hive might be located on a network drive to which you don't have access.  Can you leave some code behind to run the next time the user logs in?

Comment: @admdrew: not that simple.  If the other user isn't logged in, his or her user hive won't be loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how a while ago, I just forgot to update it here:

```
RunWait("REG" & " LOAD " & "HKU\Pos C:\Users\Pos\NTUSER.DAT", "", @SW_HIDE)
RegWrite("HKEY_USERS\Pos\somewhere", "1", "REG_SZ", $value)
RunWait("REG" & " UNLOAD " & "HKU\Pos", "", @SW_HIDE)
```

This is basically how it's done. Just load any user hive by using RunWait(). Then do anything to it like it's a normal registry. Then unload the hive.

Comment: Note that this won't work for roaming profiles if the user hasn't logged into the machine yet, or if the machine is configured to delete roaming profiles during logoff.  Looks like you're using this in-house, though, so that's OK; you would know if you were dealing with roaming profiles, and could process them on the server instead.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work

```
$fSIDList = @TEMPDIR & "\sidlist"
RunWait(@COMSPEC & ' /c WMIC useraccount get name,sid > ' & $fSIDList)
$aSIDList = FileReadToArray($fSIDList)
FileDelete($fSIDList)
; Search the array for the username you're interested in, or create a dropdown menu with it
```

You can use the values returned to access the appropriate subkey in HKEY_USERS

Comment: ... except that a user hive is only loaded when that user is logged in.